# Saving byte[] to unc file path (ADODB.Stream or PInvoke) with Silverlight5

Tags: silverlight, pinvoke

At the Moment we are using the following code to write a Byte[] to a file:

```
using (dynamic adoCom = AutomationFactory.CreateObject(@"ADODB.Stream"))
{
  adoCom.Type = adTypeBinary;
  adoCom.Open();
  adoCom.Write(fileBytes);

  adoCom.SaveToFile(filepath, adSaveCreateOverWrite);
}
```

This doesn't work with a unc path like `"\\myServer\xyz\file.docx"` (Exception CheckInvokeHResult ComAutomationFactory). If it's not an unc path, it works fine. As soon as the path Looks like this f.e. `"h:\xyz\file.docx"` it works fine.

1. Is there any solution for the Problem above?
2. How could it be solved with PInvoke?

Thank you very much.

Best regards.
Marc

Comment: Are you in-browser, in-browser trusted, or out-of-browser?

Comment: In-browser trusted or oob

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.95).aspx) is supported in SL5 trusted.